# Simulation discrepancy in 555 oscillator

Tags: simulation, 555

I've been running the simulation of a certain circuit on [falstad simulator](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=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). It's a simple square wave generator using 555 timer.

I've been trying to figure out the expected oscillation frequency, but there's a certain discrepancy between calculations and the simulation result. I would like to know where it comes from.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJYFUH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Setting the potentiometer at the exact middle (i.e. \$5\space \textrm{k}\Omega \$ on both sides), the simulator gives 180 Hz; I calculated it to be around 208 Hz. Here's my calculation:

When OUTPUT is on and DISCHARGE pin is shut out, the capacitor is charged with \$V_{cc}=5 \space \textrm V\$ through one 1N4148 and two resistors that sum up to \$6\space \textrm{k} \Omega\$. This is effectively an RC circuit with \$R=6\space \textrm{k}\Omega, \space C=500\space \textrm{nF}, V_{charge}=V_{cc}-V_{d}\$, and the voltage goes from \$\left(1/3\right)V_{cc}\$ to \$\left(2/3\right)V_{cc}\$. Here, \$V_d\$ is the diode forward voltage drop, and the simulator says it ranges from 530 to 560 mV. Let's take 540 mV for convenience. The time required for charging is then:

$$t_{charge} = \ln \left( \frac{V_{charge}-(1/3)V_{cc}}{V_{charge}-(2/3)V_{cc}} \right) \cdot R \cdot C = 0.00272 \space \textrm{sec.} $$

When the capacitor voltage reaches \$(2/3)V_{cc}\$, it discharges again through one diode and two resistors that sum up to \$6\space \textrm{k}\Omega\$. It can thus be modeled with an RC circuit discharging, but the diode does not have an effect this time. The voltage is to be halved, and the time spent is:

$$ t_{discharge} = \ln (2) \cdot R \cdot C = 0.00208\space \textrm{sec.} $$

The two figures suggest the frequency of 208.188 Hz and duty cycle 56.709%, which is quite at odds with the simulation result of 180 Hz and duty cycle 48-50%.

A few suspicions of mine would be:

- The simulator is inaccurately modeled.
- The forward voltage drop is handled wrongly in either of the charge/discharge.
- The diode does take part in discharging.
- The discharge pin was treated like a ground when discharging, but its open collector behavior is different from one.

However all these hypotheses exceed my knowledge. Can you spot what's wrong?

p.s. I'm trying to do this for PWM at 25 kHz. Do you think it's viable? I'm worried that the lower resistance and capacitance might consume more power and/or not switch on and off rapidly enough.

Comment: *Can you spot what's wrong?* - basically your expectations. If you need an accurate frequency and duty cycle don't use a 666 timer. It's for good reason that I've called the chip a 666.

Comment: also, 5V supply for a BJT 555 (like the NE555) is *really* on the edge. don't do that.

Comment: I bet you want a PWM for e.g. a motor control application. We have specifically purpose-built ICs for that problem. They are nearly as cheap as a 555 + external components, often need nothing but a single decoupling capacitor to work, and are worlds more flexible. You'll know them under the name "microcontroller"; PWM generation and load control are really two of the very core features that even the cheapest microcontrollers can do, and guess what: the frequencies they can produce are way more accurate, typically, and easier to control.

Comment: @Andyaka nice point, now I see that was off too.

Comment: @MarcusMüller On the edge as being low, I suppose? / Yes, it's for a motor, and I deliberately tried to not use microcontrollers because, well, hipster reasons. Guess I'll steer back to Arduino world...

Comment: you can do that, but there are things out there that are way more hipster than Arduino (read: more fun to work with if you don't like the Arduino approach), and often are cheaper in total cost of ownership, like [this](https://de.farnell.com/stmicroelectronics/nucleo-l010rb/entw-board-32-bit-arm-cortex-m0/dp/2845534?st=nucleo), which often still preserve at least pin-wise compatibility with arduino. I think there's even categories for such development/eval boards specifically for power / motor control, but they'll be more like 40€ than 10€, probably.

Comment: *suggest the frequency of 208.188 Hz* Real life components (resistors, capacitors) usually have 1% or 5% tolerance (resistors) and for capacitors 10% is standard. So why calculate with 6 significant digits while that 208 Hz will vary between 190 Hz to 230 Hz (roughly) in the real world? So write: 208 Hz and when you actually get 215 Hz, that's well within expected tolerances. If you need 208.188 Hz then you will need to use a crystal timer based circuit (maybe a DSS) and calibrate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The diode does have an effect on the discharge, as does the saturation voltage of the discharge output with the discharge current and the 1K load.

Rather than discharging toward 0V it is discharging towards perhaps 600mV, so discharging to 1/3 Vcc will take longer and the frequency will be lower.

That said, I don’t think the NE555 is a very good choice for this if you’re worrying about the last 10%, especially at 25kHz, and I don’t trust that particular simulator any further than I can throw it.

Comment: I guess that was it, putting that into the equation gives 183 Hz & 50% duty cycle. The frequency is OK to swing in 21k-28k, I just thought the simulation shouldn't have much of an error. I'll take the advice against NE555 and the simulator, thanks!